# GridSearchCV on a Pipeline: best_params_ seems to be wrong

Tags: scikit-learn

I am doing a gridSearch on a pipeline consisting of `StandardScaler, SelectKBest & Lasso`. The best_params_ that I get out of the following code doesn't match the param combination that minimizes the grid_scores_:

```
numComponents=np.arange(20,220,20)
alphas=np.logspace(-6,0,15)

pipe = Pipeline(steps=[('normalize', StandardScaler()), ('selectK', SelectKBest(f_regression)),     ('lasso', Lasso())])

gsObj = gridCV(pipe, dict(selectK__k=numComponents.tolist(), lasso__alpha=alphas.tolist()),     scoring='mean_squared_error', cv=10, n_jobs=3, pre_dispatch=3)
gsObj.fit(X_train, y_train)

cvMse=np.array([-score[1] for score in gsObj.grid_scores_]).reshape(len(numComponents),     len(alphas))
optNumComponents=gsObj.best_params_['selectK__k']
optAlpha=gsObj.best_params_['lasso__alpha']
```

The lowest `cvMse` comes out at `numComponents` index=5, `alpha` index=7, while from `gsObj.best_params_ optNumComponents` index=2, `optAlpha` index=9.

Am I wrong in reshaping `grid_scores_` as: `len(numComponents) x len(alphas)` (thus assuming the scores are ordered that way)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Citing the [docs](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.grid_search.GridSearchCV.html#sklearn.grid_search.GridSearchCV), `grid_scores_` is a list of named tuples in scikit-learn 0.14.1, and

> Contains scores for all parameter combinations in param_grid. Each entry corresponds to one parameter setting. Each named tuple has the attributes:
>   parameters, a dict of parameter settings
>   mean_validation_score, the mean score over the cross-validation folds
>   cv_validation_scores, the list of scores for each fold.

So no, you shouldn't rely on any order in this list, instead you should inspect the items to find out the parameters that they contain. You seem to assume that the parameters are ordered as they are in your code, but the parameter grid is a `dict`, which does not guarantee any order in its keys.

Comment: is the following incorrect in the scikit-learn examples http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/svm/plot_rbf_parameters.html ? `scores = np.array(scores).reshape(len(C_range), len(gamma_range))`

Comment: @csankar69 That example seems to make assumptions about the ordering in a `dict`, so yes, it's faulty. https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/issues/3267

Comment: On a related note, it is okay to have the Pipeline within GridSearchCV and do parallel computing (_i.e._, `n_jobs > 1`), right?

Comment: I disagree. The ordering is alphabetical. The alphabetically largest element varies fastest. That is ensured in the ``__init__``. Is that not correct?